# VB6 app sending UDP broadcast messages via winsock - only every second message is sent

Tags: windows-8, vb6, udp, winsock

I have a VB6 appl in which I have a function where I send out messages (to trace what the appl is doing) by sending UDP broadcast messages (either to 255.255.255.255 or the subnet's broadcast addr 172.16.7.255/11). The function is called from various places in the app.

I have another app the listens on the same port and displays the messages which I believe works fine.

I can run the sending app the listener app on any host in my subnet and all seems to work fine. However, when I run the sending app on Windows 8 box, I find that I only see every second message. My messages happened to be numbered and basically I just see the odd numbered messages.

I have tried to eliminate a number of possible issues by:

- Network load is minimal, and I don't see any data loss under other conditions
- The messages are quite small (less that 100 bytes each)
- I see the same behaviour when I run the listener on the same host or another host from the sending app.
- I can run the app either as an .exe or in the VB6 IDE. IN the IDE I can step over the winsock.SendData line and I still see that each second message quietly evaporates
- I have tried doing a `Sleep` and/or `DoEvents` after the send
- I tried to use the winsock events SendComplete but I suspect these are not raised for UDP
- I have written another tiny VB6 app that simply sends a number of UDP broadcasts in the same manner - and in this case all messages are sent and received by the listener correctly.
- Running the apps on other machines (which are still running XP) work fine
- I wondered if whether each second message was going somewhere else. The machine has just one NIC.
- I have confirmed that the listener application is working OK using WireShark.

The relevant code is:

```
Private WithEvents sock As Winsock
Public Sub Init()
    Set sock = new Winsock
End Sub
Public Sub Send(msg As String)
    sock.RemoteHost = "255.255.255.255"
    sock.RemotePort = 17907
    sock.SendData msg
End Sub
```

Any suggestions as to what might be going wrong, or further tests I can do.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the code you posted, UDP datagrams don't get lost at the sending end.  Pretty unguessable why it is so repeatable, this problem could be located *anywhere*.  If you don't like losing data then just use TCP.

Comment: What happens if you run both applications on the same Windows 8 box? Does the receiver see all of the data? Also, you say you have confirmed that the listener application is working OK with WireShark - does WireShark also show that only the odd-numbered messages are going out?

Comment: Running both my main app (which loses the messages) and my dummy app, both on the Win8 box I see (using both my listener app and Wireshark either on the same or another box on the subnet) the odd numbered messages from the main app and all messages from the dummy app. On an XP box, the same test gives all messages from both apps.  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **Bind** to set a local port for you app:

```
Private WithEvents sock As Winsock
Public Sub Init()
    Set sock = new Winsock
    sock.Bind 17000 'Or any other high port
End Sub

Public Sub Send(msg As String)
    sock.RemoteHost = "255.255.255.255"
    sock.RemotePort = 17907
    sock.SendData msg
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue in VBA, with access 2010. The only thing that solved the issue for me is this ( I know it doesn't make any sense ). repeat this line twice:

```
Sock.RemoteHost = DestinationIP ( for example: "192.168.0.10")
Sock.RemoteHost = DestinationIP ( same value as in the above line)
```

it works like magic:

Joe